Nesting Angular projects using Git submodule throwing compilation errors
I have two Angular projects, I would like to use project B as a sort of library for project A and project C. (I can't make it an actual Angular library due to some issues with how we deploy) I've added project B as a git submodule to project A, and in doing so I'm able to access the components offered by B. Before adding B as a submodule, both apps compiled and ran fine independently.
I'm now trying to run project A locally with a simple ng serve, but this attempts to compile and run both applications simultaneously and the result is error messages about project B not containing any necessary dependencies (i.e; x is not a known element, cannot find module, etc) . I've tried to create an .npmignore so that the subdirectory gets ignored altogether but it looks like this is a known bug (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1097). I've had difficulty finding documentation about how I'm meant to run nested Angular projects, or if there's a better solution for attempting to access the components from a project within another project that doesn't involve creating a library.
I'm not very familiar with nested Angular project structures, but it seems to me that I should need to compile or build project B and use the result within project A but I can't seem to find how to achieve that.

Why do you wish to create two separate projects then? In my opinion, you can just merge the two projects into one. Because, if you were to develop project B as a library, that's a different story. But if your project A is dependent on project B, then just merge them into one.

The components in project B will be utilized by a project C as well so it's an attempt to prevent duplicate code
